# Url for Nth google search result

Tags: url, search, web

I built a website and I have a textfield where the user puts text to search on Google. When the user selects "Search", I want to open new tabs with the first 5 results of the Google search.

Is there any sort of URL parameter that Google provides to do this? For example, the second result of a specific search-phrase?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen any way to do this.

You can do this only for the first result by adding **btnI=1** to your URL. For example, http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q=rtf will take you to the first result (which is like clicking "I'm feeling Lucky!").

**But** if you think about it, opening up 5 unknown sites is a bad idea. What if one of those sites is a phishing site. Or it has some malware that will run on the user's machine?

When I look through Google's results, I only click on "reputable" sites. I think your idea is a bit risky. I would probably never use a service like this.